# Adding Subject to Lync Chat from javascript using sip action

Tags: javascript, sip, lync-2013

I am able to open lync for a particular user on intranet which is perfectly working fine using :

```
sip:username@domain.com
```

But i am looking if i can initiate the lync with some subject from javascript  , anything like the following:

```
sip:username@domain.com?subject='this is subject'
```

Is there anything that sip/lync support in this regard ?

Thanks